# mysqli_connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql

So I've been researching this for some time.  I just want to pull data from my SQL database.  Situation is there are two servers: one web server, one SQL host.  Web server is trying to pull data from the host, and getting this error.  Both servers have windows firewall off, they are able to ping eachother, and the TCP/IP pipes are default (1433).

I have tried making the hostIP "10.10.16.55:1433" and I get a "gone away" message.  I'm at a complete loss at what is blocking this.  Please help?!

---

```
<?php




$con=mysqli_connect("10.10.16.55","sqluser","sqlpassword","sqlDB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    echo "Connection Established.<br />";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT neededColumn FROM neededView");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h1>" . "columnOutput: " . $row['neededColumn'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

---

Output to PHP Site:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: are you trying to connect or SQL Server db or MYSQl?

Comment: I have a server running SQL.  Just microsoft SQL....don't tell me it's that big of a newb mistake?!

Comment: @N.B. and he said "microsoft"????

Comment: It's definitely a SQL Server DB.  Sorry for the confusion.  Is this why it doesn't work?

Comment: @user3734732 for this issue USE PDO functionality of PHP

Comment: You can change all your code (or your database ?). But I suggest your code. SqlServer is really fine. Search for php + sqlsrv

Comment: Ah I see.  Thanks guys for the quick responses.  Time to start researching.

Comment: @user3734732 refer http://us3.php.net//manual/en/intro.pdo.php for PDO information